# Iframe not loading hosted Angular application

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe, content-management-system

we have Content management system which hosts a deployed angular app for previewing the content and currently its bind as the below

```
<iframe ng-hide="$ctrl.parent.isDisabled" ng-style="$ctrl.preset" class="am-visualization-render-area__frame" src="https://www.uat.com/homepage" style="width: 1440px; height: 768px; min-width: 1440px; min-height: 768px;" aria-hidden="false"></iframe>
```

but after angular 15 upgrade , the website is not loading in preview iframe with error as below

```
Refused to display 'https://www.uat.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

we have tried adding the X-Frame-Options as well as CSP header

```
headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'Content-Security-Policy':' frame-src '
    })
```

but so far no luck in getting back the iframe working with deployed angular

Comment: *Where* are you putting `headers: new HttpHeaders({`? That *could* be server side code responsible for serving `https://www.uat.com/`, but it seems quite likely it isn't.

Comment: yep , server team mentioned they have not set these properties in general for the site , hence they pointed out the interface between angular app & CMS is where this change should be, hence making the change in endpoint which displays the content